# How to show all comments and replies grouped by similar post

Tags: php, laravel

i want to create group of comments based on similar commentable_id (post) and display thems.

my problem is **i can't show every reply comment**. i just show **root of comment and not for reply**.

my controller to show comment

```
public function index()
{
    $mycomments = Comment::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user('member')->id)
                            ->groupBy('commentable_id')
                            ->with('replies')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->get();

    return view('frontendblog.memberlogin.home', compact('mycomments'));
}
```

and my **comment model**

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
}

public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}


public function myreplyfrom()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Comment::class,'parent_id');
}

public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class, 'parent_id');
}
```

my **comment table** like this
[image: my comment table]

my **code in view**

```
@foreach($mycomments as $comment)

                        <a href="{{ route('blog.show', $comment->commentable->slug) }}#comments"> <p>Title Post->{{ $comment->commentable->title }}</p> </a>
                        <p> Author of Post-> {{ $comment->commentable->author->name }} </p>
                        <p>Comment->{{ $comment->body }}</p>
                        @if($comment->myreplyfrom)
                            <p> Reply from Comment-> {{ $comment->myreplyfrom->body }} </p>
                        @endif
                        {!! Form::open([
                            'method' => 'POST',
                            'route' => ['comment.destroy',"id_comment" => $comment->id, "id_member" => $comment->user_id]])
                        !!}
                        {!! Form::submit('delete', [
                            'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm()',
                            'id' => 'from1',
                            ])!!}
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                        <hr/>
                    @endforeach
```

**my result**
like this

> Title Post->Quasi itaque perferendis aut animi magnam incidunt qui debitis et nesciunt assumenda saepe.
>
> Author of Post-> Ilham Firman A
>
> Comment->action 1  (Delete)
>
> ---
>
> Title Post->In incidunt provident aut atque qui.
>
> Author of Post-> Ilham Firman A
>
> Comment->woww  (Delete)

**the expected result**

> Title Post->Quasi itaque perferendis aut animi magnam incidunt qui
>   debitis et nesciunt assumenda saepe.
>
> Author of Post-> Ilham Firman A
>
> Comment->action 1               (Delete)
>
> Comment->reply action 1         (Delete)
>
> ---
>
> Title Post->In incidunt provident aut atque qui.
>
> Author of Post-> Ilham Firman A
>
> Comment->woww         (Delete)
>
> Comment->sjksjks           (Delete)
>
> Comment->sdsds            (Delete)

Comment: So do you want to show all comments, including comments that are replies, OR just the root comments?

Comment: All comments and replies but group by similar post (commentable_id),, you can see the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
->groupBy('commentable_id')
```

When you group by commentable_id, it's gonna take only ONE comment for each post from the comments table.

You could do something like this:

```
// This is a collection of comments grouped by post id, so I rename the variable to $commentsGroupedByPost.
$commentsGroupedByPost = Comment::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user('member')->id)

                            ->with('replies', 'commentable')
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->get()
                            ->groupBy('commentable_id');
```

Then from the view:

```
@foreach($commentsGroupedByPost as $postId => $comments)
    <a href="{{ route('blog.show', $comments->first()->commentable->slug) }}#comments">
        <p>Title Post->{{ $comments->first()->commentable->title }}</p> 
    </a>
   <p> Author of Post-> {{ $comments->first()->commentable->author->name }} </p>

   @foreach($comments as $comment)

        <p>Comment->{{ $comment->body }}</p>
        @foreach($comment->replies as $reply)
            <p> Reply from Comment-> {{ $reply->body }} </p>
        @endforeach
        {!! Form::open([
            'method' => 'POST',
            'route' => ['comment.destroy',"id_comment" => $comment->id, 
            "id_member" => $comment->user_id]])
        !!}
        {!! Form::submit('delete', [
            'onclick' => 'deleteConfirm()',
            'id' => 'from1',
        ])!!}
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    @endforeach
    <hr/>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Property [commentable] does not exist on this collection instance. 
`->with('replies', 'commentable')` ? 
 `$postId => $comments` and how you call it in `$comment->commentable->slug`, so it will be undefined variable.

Comment: Sorry, I miss one foreach loop. The answer has been updated.

Comment: okay. I appreciate your efforts, but it's still iterate the title of post.

Comment: Haha, it sucks that I cannot see the result straightaway to fix the issues. I have just updated both the query and the view.

Comment: Property [commentable] does not exist on this collection instance. 
i thinks your nearly fix this issues.

Comment: i think you don't need to add `->whereNull('parent_id')` . because it's show just root of comments.

Comment: It depends on your requirements. I make sense to me to get only the root comments and eager load the replies.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure of what you are trying to achieve, but I think you are trying to get the first comment/reply only?

If so please try this:

```
$mycomments = Comment::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user('member')->id)
        ->groupBy('commentable_id')
        ->with(['replies', function($query) {
            $query->latestFirst();
        }])
        ->get();
```

I'm not sure what your latestFirst() method is doing but the closure I have added should give you the first instance of the reply/comments.

Comment: error. `mb_strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`.
you can see the expected result.

Comment: latestFirst , scope for order comment by created_at

Comment: i want to show every comments and replies, not first from comment,.

Comment: I have edited the solution, hopefully that will do what you are after.

Comment: If i use your code , then the result is same as with me. I dont need to add query like that, because the problem is not there. You can see the expected result must be showed

Comment: Oke. I still thanks for your comment and my problem was fixed.

Comment: No worries, glad you sorted it